# Retrieve counts of a specific column while inlcude the single line's primary key

Tags: sql-server, count

I have a table1  and this table1 has following records in it. **ID** is the primary key and I would like to count number of each **UserID** appearances.

```
select UserID, count(UserID) as Qty from Table1 group by UserID
```

SQL query above works for me but, I also want my query to include **ID value** as well if any result line with one count.

By doing this I am trying to avoid another query for the single records that I want to work on.

```
Table1

ID UserID Amount
-- ------ ------
 1     11    100
 2     12    200
 3     12    150
 4     11    160
 5     13    100
 6     12    150
 7     14    120
```

result query should be like below

```
UserID Qty ID
------ --- --  
    11   2  
    12   3
    13   1  5 
    14   1  7
```

Is there a way to create such query with a single select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `MAX` with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT
    UserID,
    COUNT(*) AS Qty,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN MAX(ID) END AS ID
FROM Table1
GROUP BY
    UserID
ORDER BY
    UserID;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

We display the (one and only) `ID` value should the count for a given user be 1, otherwise we just display `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `left join` to get ID with `QTY  = 1`

```
select t1.UserID, t1.Qty, coalesce(t2.ID, '') as ID
from    
    (select UserID, count(UserID) as Qty
    from Table1
    group by UserID) t1
left join Table1 t2 on t1.Qty = 1 and t1.UserID = t2.UserID
```

Comment: this answer is correct as well, bu I think answer with the CASE statement is more simple for me since I am using result in a LEFT JOIN statement. I wonder which way is more efficient.